# What is the most general formulation of Gauss's circle problem?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The (in)famous Gauss circle problem asserts that the usual error term for counting integral points inside a circle of radius $R$ centred at the origin can be made much smaller. In particular, by using a simple geometry of numbers argument one gets

$$\displaystyle \# \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2\} = \pi R^2 + O \left(R \right).(1)$$

Gauss's circle problem is the conjecture that the error term $O(R)$ can be replaced by $O(R^{1/2})$. By the work of Voronoi, one now has the exponent $2/3$ (i.e., an error term of $O(R^{2/3})$) and by work of Huxley one can replace this exponent by $131/208$.

One can formulate Gauss's circle problem in modern language. Let $N(X)$ denote the number of (necessarily principal) ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ having norm bounded by $X$. Then the conjecture is equivalent to the assertion that

$$\displaystyle N(X) = \frac{\pi X}{4} + O \left(X^{1/4} \right),$$

the factor of $1/4$ introduced because the Gaussian integers $\pm x \pm iy$ generate the same ideal.

If we instead fix a number field $K$ of degree $n \geq 2$ and fix an ideal class $C$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, denote by $N_K(C;X)$ for the number of ideals belonging to $C$ having norm bounded by $X$. Then the analogous theorem to (1) is

$$\displaystyle N_K(C;X) = \frac{\kappa(K) X}{h(K)} + O_n \left((h(K) R(K))^{1/n}(1 + \log h(K) R(K))^{(n-1)^2/n} X^{1- 1/n} \right),(2)$$

where $h(K)$ is the class number of $K$, $R(K)$ the regulator of $K$, and $\kappa_K$ the residue at $s = 1$ of the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$ (this being a theorem of Korneel Debaene; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.10103). In particular, for $n = 2$ (2) exactly recovers (1).

My question is, what is the correct formulation of 'Gauss's circle problem' for (2)? What is the expected optimal exponent in $X$, and what is the expected dependency on the regulator/class number terms?