# Another generalization of the Gauss circle problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355861/what-is-the-most-general-formulation-of-gausss-circle-problem) I asked for a generalization of the Gauss circle problem, the type of generalization I am asking is to view the Gauss circle problem as one about counting algebraic integers of bounded norm.

A more geometric generalization is the following: let $\Lambda$ be a unimodular lattice in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (that is, it has determinant $\pm 1$). Consider the counting function

$\displaystyle N_\Lambda(X) = \# \{(u,v) \in \Lambda : u^2 + v^2 \leq X \}.$

Then by geometry of numbers, one has

$$\displaystyle N_\Lambda(X) = \pi X + O_\Lambda\left(X^{1/2} \right).$$

Thus a generalized version of Gauss's circle problem is to ask: how does the error term $O_\Lambda\left(X^{1/2}\right)$ depend on $\Lambda$, and can the exponent be made to be $1/4$?

It can be shown that the error term certainly cannot be made to be independent of $\Lambda$, since if $\Lambda$ has an extremely short vector then there can be arbitrarily many multiples of that vector sitting inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 \leq X$.

Comment: Equivalently, we can study integral points in ellipsoids, and p. 95 of [this PhD thesis](https://www.icmat.es/Thesis/2018/Tesis_Carlos_Pastor_Alcoceba.pdf) has a nice survey.